# Configuration of open web analytics locally

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, javascript

I try to run the [openwebanalytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/) software locally under wampserver and joomla using the instructions of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cj-d8HJYH2k).

I have created the db.

I have insert the owa file under the joomla site.

I type in my browser the path for the file

```
  http://localhost/openwebanalytics/owa/install.php
```

and press the start button.

In the next step I get this [image: error] but I can insert the data for the db.

I press the button for the next step and I get only warnings.

What could be possible wrong with the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, are you sure you need to install OWA on localhost? I don't see any important reasons for this, as you'll still need to have it on a web server in order to track anything.

Your error states that `preg_replace` using the `/e` modifier is deprecated. This is [deprecated as of PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php), thus I'm guessing you're using Wampserver with PHP 5.5. According to the [OWA Technical Requirements](http://wiki.openwebanalytics.com/index.php?title=Technical_Requirements), the software requires PHP 5.2.x or later, but it looks like PHP 5.5 is not fully supported yet.

I suggest you install OWA on a webserver running PHP 5.4.x until PHP 5.5 is fully supported. If you have to use it on your localhost, you can find older versions of [Wampserver at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but I have a problem with joomla installation. It takes to much time to install the new site even if I used an older version of joomla.

Comment: You don't need an older version of Joomla, Joomla is independent of your PHP version. But I agree that reinstalling wampserver also takes time. Any particular reason you want to run OWA on localhost?

Comment: Yes it is for teaching / learning purpose.

Comment: @foc Then you might have to switch to [Wampserver 2.4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/Wampserver%202.4/), this version comes with PHP 5.4.

Comment: Yes I tried this solution but I think that I have a problem with the installation of Joomla. Everything works perfect until the 3rd step of Joomla installation / configuration. It sticks in the 3rd step "creating database tables". It shows that it is in process but for about an hour it is in the same situation. I checked the db of joomla and it has some tables. I don't encounter this problem with the newest version of wamp.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that problem sometimes, not sure how to get around it, though. Have you tried [xampp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/)?

Comment: I will test it as alternative solution if I can find one with php 5.4 or previous. Thank you.